# Uploading files with MVC 3 ajax style

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, html

Maybe it's just me but I'm trying to use a jQuery dialog to capture a file the user wants to upload. **It must be supported by IE9**. IE9 doesn't support the FormData object which is used in many examples and 3rd party tools I have came across. So in order to make my request not refresh the whole page I have to put my upload into an iFrame? Really? I know I can get some flash uploader but flash isn't supported on our site so that's out of the question right now.

Please.. please someone tell me I'm doing this wrong and there's an easier way because I can't seem to find it.. not one that will work on IE9 at least.

Form

```
<form action="/ControllerName/ActionName" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Then into an iFrame like this

```
<iframe src="myUrl"></iframe>
```

Comment: What's wrong with using an iFrame? If you place it in a lightbox/dialog the user can't tell the difference.

Comment: @SpencerRuport It just feels hackish to me like it should be done in a better way.

Comment: It should. But as developers we're simply victims of browser wars.

Comment: What about an ajaxified form using `Ajax.BeginForm`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.beginform.aspx

Comment: @mattytommo I tried using that first thing. The ajax object doesn't support file uploads :( Then I tried just a normal form, serializing it and using ajax to pass the data but that doesn't work either I'm pretty sure it's due to the way HTTP transports files in multi part posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FileUpload","Message",FormMethod.Post,new { enctype="multipart/form-data"})) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Message</legend>

//your html here

                                <input type="file" name="files"/>

    </fieldset>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult FileUpload(FormCollection values, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
        {
             //do what you want with form values then for files

           foreach (var file in files)
            {
                if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    byte[] fileData = new byte[file.ContentLength];
                    file.InputStream.Read(fileData, 0, file.ContentLength);

                   //do what you want with fileData
                }
            }
        }
```

I provide multiple files upload so i use

```
IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files
```

if you want only a single file then use only

```
HttpPostedFileBase file
```

and in your view change input type to

```
<input type="file" name="file"/>
```

Simple as that. 
Regards

EDITED:

Take a look at more good examples:

http://www.strathweb.com/2012/04/html5-drag-and-drop-asynchronous-multi-file-upload-with-asp-net-webapi/

http://css.dzone.com/articles/implementing-html5-drag-drop

Regards

Comment: I swear I saw this solution somewhere before and tried it. But to humor myself I tried it again. The problem I have here is "files" comes back as null. I tried getting rid of the IEnumerable too and just having file with no luck.. still null

Comment: Since the question was about making asynchronous call to the server through Ajax, Html.BeginForm would not help.

Comment: I know this was a long time ago but this is what I ended up doing in the end with an iFrame.

Comment: What has this answer got to do with ajax?